# Several Typescript (is not assignable to parameter of type) errors on Reduce function

Tags: javascript, typescript, reduce

```
[ts]
Argument of type '(sum: number, wallet: IConvertedRate) => number' is not assignable to parameter of type '(previousValue: number, currentValue: "" | { convertedRate: number; }, currentIndex: number, array: ("" | { convertedRate: number; })[]) => number'.

Types of parameters 'wallet' and 'currentValue' are incompatible.
Type '"" | { convertedRate: number; }' is not assignable to type 'IConvertedRate'.
Type '""' is not assignable to type 'IConvertedRate'. [2345]
```

Not sure how to address these Typescript errors

### logs

This is what `wallets` looks like:

```
[
  { currency: 'USD', amount: 100 },
  { currency: 'EUR', amount: 500 }
  { currency: 'CHF', amount: 10000 }
]
```

This is what `convertedRates` looks like:

```
[
  { convertedRate: 100 },
  { convertedRate: 437,44 }
  { convertedRate: 9980.9 }
]
```

This code below works and returns the correct total value of `10518.34`, but can't get rid of the typescript error.

### Code

```
interface IConvertedRate {
  convertedRate: number;
}

calculateTotalValue(wallets: IWallet[]) {
  const { assets } = this.props;

  const convertedRates = wallets.map((wallet) => {
    const conversion = assets.filter((asset) => asset.currency === wallet.currency)[0];

    if (conversion) {
      return {
        convertedRate: roundFloat(wallet.amount * conversion.rate, 2)
      };
    }

    return '';
  });

  const total = convertedRates.reduce(function(sum: number, wallet: IConvertedRate) {
    return sum + wallet.convertedRate;
  }, 0);

  console.log('total', total);
  return total.toString();
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the body of your `map` function returns `return '';`, so signature of `convertedRates` is `''|IConvertedRate`. You need to rewrite the body of the map function to always return an `IConvertedRate`, or you force a cast

Comment: Thanks! `return { convertedRate: 0 };`